# Is it possible to print from local pc default printer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, crystal-reports, rdlc

Work on **vs2005** Asp.net C# Application ,face problem on printer setup on my report. After deploy the application on server **iis** ,if I give print command from my  local pc , **rdlc** report viewer page application run print command on  my server pc’s default set printer but I want to print from my local pc’s default set  printer.

I'd like to have a "Print" button on that page, which prints a specific set of information to the default printer attached to the client machine.

Is this possible from **asp.net C#**? I have found things online about printing to a printer attached to the server, but that's not really what I want. What I do?

Any type of suggestion will be acceptable, if have any query please ask. Thanks in advanced

Comment: http://www.webblogsforyou.com/how-to-print-asp-net-gridview-data-on-button-click-using-javascript/

Comment: eddie_cat thanks for your reply,it's can not solve my problem because my report is custom designed so print on grid can not full fill my requirement.

Comment: The point is that you need to use JavaScript to print client side... surely you can see how you could adapt this code to your own situation. Since you haven't given us any information about the specifics of rendering your print document, I assume you're not looking for exact guidance on that.

Comment: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Printing-Reporting.aspx

Comment: Who given the downvotes, its very valid question. Every business application want this type of requirement. Its up to us, to give proper or related answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the user invoke the printing functionality from the browser, where they can control the printer and any other choices they might want (double-sided, landscape/portrait, etc.)  If the default report format is better for presentation in the browser than printing, you can give them a link to a "printer friendly version" and let them print from there.

Answer (score 0):

Its true, and never change as you want. The reason is crystal report is run on server, whenever you click button. So while print, it always print on the server's default printer, not client default printer.

This is the server side technology, now you want to print on client side.

The easiest way to any how you generate a HTML page and on that page run the print script which populate the list of printer on client machine, even if you run direct commant to print , it print on client's default printer.

Please check first this link : http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-52407

Here is some link if above not work

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/262485/how-to-print-crystal-report-in-printer-in-client-m

[Crystal Reports export to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608498/crystal-reports-export-to-html)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chriswong1/ExportCrystalReportInASPNET11092005010905AM/ExportCrystalReportInASPNET.aspx